# Pass multiple parameters in batch file

Tags: search, parameters, batch-file

I have a winform app that prompts the user to input two search parameters.

When executed these parameters are passed into a `run.bat` file i.e.

```
call search.bat %1 %2
```

Where `%1 %2` are the parameters that were input by the user in the winform.

This then should put the parameters into the `search.bat` part of a search URL which is-

```
"http://www.foo.com/search=%*"
```

I thought that the `%*` would take both parameters added and do the search but for some reason it brings back results for both parameters `%1` + `%2` and then results for just `%2`.

Is it possible to edit this so that it only brings back results for any parameters entered by the user?

Comment: i tried this for yahoo

"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AtRpAnvHsS_2IiSdgT_TfYubvZx4?p=%*&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-701"

%* seems to work fine.

search.bat test 123 456

makes search for "test 123 456" as expected and nothing more after it.

Comment: its odd, it may just be the way the url search engine works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its turns out I was not clearing the cache folder after every search, therefore old search terms were being submitted.